# How can I make the content of multiple folders appear as one virtual folder or drive letter?

Tags: filesystems, symbolic-link, windows-server-2012, folder-redirection

I have been wanting to do this for a while now and have looked up union FS and symoblic links and all sorts of filesystems like ZFS. But I am not so sure that my needs are that complex I just can't find the answer :-(.

I am an avid Photographer and I have a ton of Raw photos, TB in fact.

My problem is that I am loosing track of of what files are where and on which drive etc...

So here is what I would like/love to do..

Take E:\Canon\Photos, F:\Canon\Photos and G:\Canon\Photos..

combine or Union or whatever it would be called to create say P:\Canon\Photos that shows me the contents of the 3 above ?? I understand it would be for Read purposes only.

So is this possible ? its like 3 identical folder structures on 3 drives that I want to combine as one for reading purposes ?

Help that makes sense

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Sorry Windows server 2012

Comment: Would [Distributed File System](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753479%28WS.10%29.aspx) be what your looking for?

Answer (score 1):

About the closest thing you can do on Windows to get a merged **view** of the folders is to setup and use a Library.

- The library option may be hidden - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/3fea0c19-0ae3-4c9c-a737-b228a06f8b57/show-libraries-in-file-explorer
- How to create a library and add folders - http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10283/understanding-the-libraries-feature-in-windows-7/

Another option that would probably take a lot more work would be to Backup all your drives to external media, then delete all your filesystems, and create a new filesystem based off a [storage space](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831739(v=ws.11).aspx).  Storage spaces are more flexible then traditional RAID, and you can add and remove storage pretty easily.  You can have dissimilar drives in the pool.  With storage spaces, you only have one single 'drive', or rather one single filesystem that spans many drives.  If you do take this route do consider using the options to setup redundancy, since a failed individual without any redundancy can result in the loss of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I used mkdir, mklink and subst commands as below.

```
mkdir <root-folder>
cd <root-folder>
mklink /d <first-target-new-name> <link-to-first-sub-folder>
mklink /d <second-target-new-name> <link-to-second-sub-folder>
subst <drive_name>: <root-folder>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).